# Map function and inside filter function

Tags: reactjs

I need to make .map to display label name and after when i get id from map i need to filter where id from .map is same in second array and display all same ids

FIRST array to .map

```
[{"id":"14","name":"Certifikace"},{"id":"17","name":"Instalace"}]
```

SECOND array to .filter with id from first array

```
[{"filter_name_id":"14","text":"CE"},{"filter_name_id":"14","text":"PZTS"},{"filter_name_id":"14","text":"Železnice"},{"filter_name_id":"17","text":"Volný podklad"},{"filter_name_id":"17","text":"DIN35"},{"filter_name_id":"17","text":"Do 10\" stojanu"},{"filter_name_id":"17","text":"Do 19\" stojanu"},{"filter_name_id":"17","text":"Na sloup"}]
```

My current code

```
{
  filterListDataName &&
    filterListDataName.map(
      function (item, id) {
        return (
          <label>{item.name}</label>
          //here need to add filter with (item.id) from filterListDataText.filter()
        );
      }.bind(this)
    );
}
```

Thank you.

Comment: you can transform data to component using map function but not with filter function so firstly you should use filter function and after map function.

Comment: Oh, i need to get item.id filterListDataName.map and after i can filter that. Thank you.

Comment: `.map(function(...){...}.bind(this))` is a `bind` anti-pattern. `.map` allows you to specify the context as the second argument, ie `.map(function(...){...}, this)`. Another modern alternative is to use an arrow function, which preserves the lexical context, `.map((...) => {...})` and so there is no need for passing dynamic context.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the data we set as dataName and dataNameText:

```
const dataName = [
  {"id":"14","name":"Certifikace"},
  {"id":"17","name":"Instalace"}
];

const dataNameText = [
  {"filter_name_id":"14","text":"CE"},
  {"filter_name_id":"14","text":"PZTS"}, 
  {"filter_name_id":"14","text":"Železnice"}, 
  {"filter_name_id":"17","text":"Volný podklad"}, 
  {"filter_name_id":"17","text":"DIN35"},
  {"filter_name_id":"17","text":"Do 10\" stojanu"}, 
  {"filter_name_id":"17","text":"Do 19\" stojanu"}, 
  {"filter_name_id":"17","text":"Na sloup"}
];
```

then the filteredDataNameText name will be:

```js
return (
   ...
    <ul>
      {dataName.map((item) => {
        return (
          <li>
            <label>{item.name}</label>
            <ul>
              {dataNameText
                .filter((dT) => dT.filter_name_id === item.id)
                .map((filtered) => {
                  return <li>{filtered.text}</li>;
              })}
            </ul>
          </li>
        );
      })}
    </ul>
   ...
)
```

But if you use functional component, you can use useMemo to memoize the filtered data:
[image: Edit async-cookies-l9d9kz]

```js
  const listDataName = useMemo(() => {
    return dataName.map((data) => {
      return {
        ...data,
        dataText: dataText.filter((dt) => dt.filter_name_id === data.id)
      };
    });
  }, []);
```

and render it as follows:

```js
 return (
    <>
      ...
      <ul>
        {listDataName.map((item) => {
          return (
            <li>
              <label>{item.name}</label>
              <ul>
                {item.dataText.map((dtText) => {
                  return <li>{dtText.text}</li>;
                })}
              </ul>
            </li>
          );
        })}
     </ul>
     ...
   </>
 )
```

Comment: Yes! Thats what i wanted, you helped me lots of, thank you so much.